# How to search for files with given extensions in multiple directories?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
set path="D:\Work,D:\workin,D:\files"
set files ="txt,html,xml"
```

How to search for files with an extension defined in `files` in the directories defined in `path` and write their names into a file?

Here is what I have tried already:

```
set "list=list.txt"
pause

pushd "%~dp0"
>"%list%" (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('2^>nul dir /ad /b') do (
    pushd "%%i"
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('2^>nul dir /a-d /b *.txt *.html') do (
        echo %%j& >nul 2>&1 copy/y "%%j" ..
    )
    popd
)
)
popd
```

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: Start your batch file coding task with reading [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) and with reading [What is the reason for '…' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) and you know what you have made already wrong in the first two posted lines.

Comment: I highly suggest you never name a variable `PATH`.  It is already a system variable and now you have changed it for that session which may cause some of your commands to not run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify this process by using a standard `FOR` command.

```
@Echo off

>"FileList.log" (
for %%G in (D:\Work,D:\workin,D:\files) do (
    pushd "%%~G"
    for %%H in (*.xml *.txt *.html) do (
        echo %%~H
        copy /y "%%~H" ..
    )
    popd
)
)
```

Comment: how to search in subfolders?

Comment: @PŖŌtein-, open up a cmd prompt and read the help for the `FOR` command. At the cmd prompt type: `FOR /?`.  You only need to add two characters to the code.